# Adding href for each array items

Tags: php, arrays

im trying to create a tags from array items and the number of array items is always different,

```
$myarray = 'sports,politics,entertainment,celebs';
$siteurl = 'http://example.com/';
$tag = explode(',', $myarray);
```

this is what i do

```
echo '<p>tag : <a href="'.$siteurl.'?'.$tag[0].'" >'.$tag[0].'</a>, 



<a href="'.$siteurl.'?'.$tag[1].'" >'.$tag[1].'</a>, 
<a href="'.$siteurl.'?'.$tag[2].'" >'.$tag[2].'</a>, 
<a href="'.$siteurl.'?'.$tag[3].'" >'.$tag[3].'</a>,
<a href="'.$siteurl.'?'.$tag[4].'" >'.$tag[4].'</a></p>';
```

how can i echo this tags with a single call and get all array items no mather how much the items number?

Edit : typo for $vatag

Comment: Use a foreach loop, or a for loop

Comment: From where does this `$vatag` came?

Comment: you could try explode like this:  `$tag = explode('<a href="' . $myarray->siteurl . '?' . $myarray->tag[1]. '" >' . $myarray->vatag[1] . '</a>', $myarray);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a foreach loop to accomplish this, as follows:

```
$myarray = 'sports,politics,entertainment,celebs';
$siteurl = 'http://example.com/';
$tag = explode(',', $myarray);

foreach($tag as &$value) {
    echo '<a href="'.$siteurl.'?'.$value.'" >'.$value.'</a>';
}
```

The result:

```
<a href="http://example.com/?sports" >sports</a><a href="http://example.com/?politics" >politics</a><a href="http://example.com/?entertainment" >entertainment</a><a href="http://example.com/?celebs" >celebs</a>
```

Comment: just  an observation, no need to  pass  by reference in the loop

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix sorry its a typo

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I don't see a second array. It was a typo and the question is now corrected by the user I think.

Answer (score 1):

Then you can do them like this:

```
$len = count($tag);
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
   echo '<a href="'.$siteurl.'?'.$tag[$i].'" >'.$tag[$i].'</a>';
}
```

So the full code

```
$myarray = 'sports,politics,entertainment,celebs';
$siteurl = 'http://example.com/';
$tag = explode(',', $myarray);

$len = count($tag);
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
   echo '<a href="'.$siteurl.'?'.$tag[$i].'" >'.$tag[$i].'</a>';
}
```

Another, slightly more advanced way is like this (which is what I typically do)

```
$myarray = 'sports,politics,entertainment,celebs';
$siteurl = 'http://example.com/';
$tag = explode(',', $myarray);

$html = array_map(function($item)use($siteurl){
    return '<a href="'.$siteurl.'?'.$item.'" >'.$item.'</a>';
}, $tag);

echo implode("\n",$html);
```

That way in the source code for the page each link is on a new line, which makes it a bit easier to read the source.  You can implode with "", for no line return too.

Cheers!

Comment: I am not sure I know what you mean?.  I do post some long answers though....  If that is what you mean, sorry, I just try to explain things as best I can.  At the moment my wrists really hurt, so ....  I been slammed updating `mysql_` and other pre 7 stuff,  I remember when it changed from 4 to 5, all those constructors and other things...

Comment: Sorry, should have been more explicit.  meant to say you'd dropped the original paragraphs and commas from the html output.  Shame there isn't something like python 2 to 3!  Poor you.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a foreach loop, which will run through event element of the array, regardless of its length.

```
// Start with initialising an empty string
$str = '';

// Loop through every element of the $tag array,
//   using $value to hold the value of the current element in the loop
foreach ($tag as $value) {
  // Append the new link to the end of the string
  $str .= '<a href="' . $siteurl . '?' . $value . '" >' . $value . '</a>' . ', ';
}

// Echo the final array, after trimming off any spaces or commas
//   from the end
echo '<p>tag :' . rtrim($str, ', ') . '</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `$vatag` array, or do you? You can't match something that you don't have or if you have it show us its' contents.

Simply use this code:

```
$siteurl = 'http://example.com/';
$tags = explode(',', 'sports,politics,entertainment,celebs');
echo '<p>Tags: ';
foreach($tags as $tag) {
    echo "<a href=\"{$siteurl}?{$tag}\">{$tag}&nbsp;</a>";
}
echo '</p>';
```